# What is the rationale for making intptr_t and uintptr_t optional types?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The C Standard defines `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` in `<stdint.h>` this way:

> **7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers**
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> intptr_t
> ```
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> uintptr_t
> ```
>
> These types are optional.

Why are these types **optional**?
Are there any examples of architectures where these types cannot be defined?

Comment: I don't want to bother and your question is more illustrative but what about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53380203/12139179)? Do you want to ask explicit with C (not C/C++ mishmash) and C standard focus or does this answer your question?

Comment: I seem to recall there exist microcontrollers with 8-bit general-purpose registers, and 16-bit special-purpose registers for memory access.

Comment: C committee has a long lasting problem with existing ABIs and some integer types for example `intmax_t`.  To avoid similar problems but to be flexible at the same time they decided to make some types which may  cause similar ABI problems optional.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Indeed the question in reference does answer mine. SO's duplicate finder in the Ask Question page is ineffective. I also do not understand why the other question is tagged c++.

Comment: @chqrlie Experienced the same. Since a while, I always use Google to look for questions on SO.

Comment: @chqrlie In ISO C++ they are optional, too. - Ref.: C++17, 21.4.1

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Well, `int` is required to be at least 16 bits, so such a machine has to be able to support 16-bit integers anyway, at which point it might as well `typedef int intptr_t;`.